# Method that returns one of multiple data types

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I'm writing a parser and I have a method that receives an expression and returns a single object that can be either `string`, `int`, `Version` or `DateTime`, currently it's defined as such like:

```
private object EvaluateExpression(Expression expression)
```

Because I don't know what the expression will return until it is evaluated by `EvaluateExpression`, I can't use generics.

It seems like the options are either to continue using `object` as the return method (which means boxing and unboxing later on) or use `dynamic` (which should be even more expensive than boxing/unboxing from some rudimentary testing I did).

What other options do I have available?

Comment: You already listed the available options. I don´t know any other one.

Comment: This question is a little too broad. Think of JObject, or how other parsers achieve things. However if you are looking for low allocations and lightening speed then this really depends on exactly what you are doing. Boxing is the least of your concerns